# mutation(["hello", "Hello"]); - Return true if Hello is equal to hello but my code returns false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I am comparing t to u which returns the same string which is "HELLO" but my
   code returns false instead of true.  I have also tried the array.indexOf() 
   function and still the same result.  Help please.

```
function mutation(arr) {
    var uppercaseArray = arr.toString().toUpperCase().split(","),
        t = uppercaseArray[0].toString();
        u = uppercaseArray[1].toString(),
        n = t.localeCompare(u);
    if (n = 1) {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }  
}

mutation(["hello", "Hello"])
```

Comment: `if( n = 1 )` is assignment. You're assigning 1 to n. You're looking for `if( n == 1 )` which is comparison.

Comment: I have used n ==1 as well and it still returns false.

Comment: @LisaMFlath: You're looking for `n==0` - `localeCompare` returns `0` for equal strings.

Comment: You really really should not use that `uppercaseArray` approach - think what happens when one of the strings contains a comma. Just use `var t = arr[0].toString().toUpperCase(); var u = arr[1].toString().toUpperCase();` and then `return u == t;`

Answer (score 1):

`if(n = 1)` will always be true, I think you're looking for `==` or `===`

Comment: thanks but i have tried that as well and the function still returns false.

Comment: Ah but localCompare() returns 0 if 2 values are the same, not 1

Comment: figured it out.  if the strings are the same, this will return a 0 and not a 1.  :)

Comment: Code should look like this:                                                                function mutation(arr) {
var uppercaseArray = arr.toString().toUpperCase().split(",");
t = uppercaseArray[0].toString();
u = uppercaseArray[1].toString();
var n = t.localeCompare(u);
if (n == 0) {
return true; 
} else {
return false;
}  
}

Comment: @LisaMFlath: or rather `return n == 0;`

Comment: Like @Felix said, be much cleaner to just return [n == 0] :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change to `if (n == 0) {`

```
function mutation(arr) {
    var uppercaseArray = arr.toString().toUpperCase().split(",");
    t = uppercaseArray[0].toString();
    u = uppercaseArray[1].toString();
    var n = t.localeCompare(u);
    if (n == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
console.log(mutation(["hello", "Hello"]));
```

The [localCompare](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp) function returns 0 when they are equal.